# File ownership in 13.04 set to messagebus instead of syslog for /var/log files

Tags: upgrade, permissions, log, ownership

Forgive me if this has been asked and answered already, I did search and couldn't find anything.

On 12.10, /var/log files were written to. auth.log, syslog, and others. However, both fresh install and upgrades to 13.04 result in auth.log and other files being empty. Looking at the ownership, I see at least auth.log and a couple of others are now owned in 13.04 by messagebus:adm instead of syslog:adm as they were in 12.10 and earlier. Changing the file ownership to syslog:adm on auth.log results in it being written to again.

My question is, why are permissions being set this way in 13.04 and how do I go about reverting everything to what they should be? My concern is that I may be able to fix a few things, but I have no idea what else isn't getting written to as a result of this possible bug.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it with `sudo find /var/log -type f -user messagebus -exec chown syslog:adm {} \;`